# Window flags not helping in mdiarea in Qt

Tags: qt

I am using Qt and creating a GUI with multiple sub windows. I am using MDI Area for the same. I want to hide the top toolbar of mdi subwindow but using window flags is not helping.

I have tried writing the code as follows. First I tried for mdiarea and then for subwindow but neither worked.

mdiarea.setWindowsFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

subwindow.setWindowsFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

I have also tried using Qt::CustomizedWindowHint but even that is not helping. Please help me with this.

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'top toolbar'? A [toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolbar) is the area that has buttons on it (like the Ribbon interface in Microsoft Office programs). Do you mean the [titlebar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titlebar)?

Comment: yes the title bar...sorry mixed up two things...Thank you for the reply...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mdiArea->addSubWindow(new QLabel("Qt::FramelessWindowHint"), Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

You don't want to set the MDI area itself as a frameless window, because it's a widget you likely have embedded in another window... it most likely already doesn't have a frame.

Your setting the 'subwindow' should work... but `addSubWindow(myWidget)` actually wraps the widget passed in in the *real* subwindow, so that's what was going wrong. Qt lets you pass in window flags as the second parameter of `addSubWindow()` and those flags go to the real subwindow.

Note that with a frameless window, you can't drag the window around to move it, or grab the edges to resize it, because there's nothing for you to grab onto!

If you just want the minimize and maximize buttons gone (but still want the close button), try passing `Qt::Dialog` instead.

Try also experimenting with these:

```
addSubWindow(new QLabel("Qt::Tool"), Qt::Tool);
addSubWindow(new QLabel("Qt::Tool|Qt::CustomizeWindowHint"), Qt::Tool|Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
addSubWindow(new QLabel("Qt::Dialog"), Qt::Dialog);
```

I think `Qt::Tool|Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` is probably the best option (no buttons, but still movable and resizable - if you don't want it resizable, give it a fixed size (`setFixedSize()`).

**Edit:** Also try: `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint|Qt::WindowTitleHint`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is I am using Qt Designer to create the mdi subwindows and hence I tried writing directly in the code. Is there any way this can be done if I have made the MDIArea in Designer....

Comment: In my example (though not visible from what I posted) my MDIArea was created in Designer, but my widgets were added in the code. If your widgets (the subwindows) are created in designer also, then try this: *mySubWindow->parentWidget()->setWindowFlags(...);*  (remembering that your widgets are actually wrapped in the real MDI subwindows, and hopefully taking advantage of that - but I haven't tested it).

Comment: Hey I got the solution. I used the slot subwindow activated and in that I gave mdiArea.activatedSubwindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)....Thanks a lot for your help... :)